# list of links if the hrefs are the same replace the text jQuery

Tags: jquery, hyperlink

I have a list of links, some of which might be duplicate href's but the link text itself has been edited slightly.

At the minute, to get rid of the duplicates I have been using this code.

```
var seen = {};
 $('.sortable li div a').each(function() {
  var txt = $(this).text();
  var linkTxt = $(this).attr("href");
   if (seen[linkTxt]){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    var sortableList = $(".sortable").html();
    $("#ItemDescription").val(sortableList);
   }else{
    seen[linkTxt] = true;
    $(".sortable li div").each(function(){
    var selectLength = $(this).find("input").length;
     if(selectLength == 0){
      $("<input type='checkbox' name='selected' class='select'/>").appendTo(this);
     }
 });
```

This code is just removing it, I need the code to replace the linkText at the top with the linkText nearer the bottom(newest goes here), then remove it, but only if the href's match.

Anyone any ideas?

my list looks like this

```
<ol class="sortable ui-sortable" style="float:right;"><li class="menu-item">
<div class="">Allure<input type="checkbox" name="selected" class="x_x_x_select"></div>
<ol class="">
    <li style="display: list-item;" class="">
    <div class=""><a href="/portfolios/energy-drink" class="" name="">Energy-Drink</a><input type="checkbox" name="selected" class="x_x_select"></div>
    </li>
</ol>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">
<div class="">Avon<input type="checkbox" name="selected" class="x_x_x_select"></div>
</li>
<li class="menu-item">
<div class="">Bitten SJP<input type="checkbox" name="selected" class="x_x_x_select"></div>
</li>
<li style="display: list-item;" class="">
    <div class=""><a href="/portfolios/energy-drink" class="" name="">Allure-Energy-Drink</a><input type="checkbox" name="selected" class="x_x_select"></div>
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Why would you want to first change the link text if you will remove it?

Comment: so the menu is a nested list.. I want to check the items at the bottom  (which are new but NOT placed) and if there already is an item with the same HREF I want to remove it from the bottom but first I want to replace the A text in the nested item with the newer A text, just added to the bottom, then when that's done I want to remove the item from the bottom, it might not be making any sense. sorry

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correwctly, you want to take the item from the bottom, search for an according item on the top, replace that one's text and remove the element from the bottom.

```
var changed = true;
while(changed) {
    changed = false;
    $('.sortable li div a').each(function() {
        var all = $('.sortable li div a[href=' + $(this).attr('href') + ']');
        if(all.length > 1) {
            all.first().text(all.last().text());
            all.slice(1).remove();
            changed = true;
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for, but for some reason, it's not working, is this inside another function? Thanks so much for your help!